# Carácter nulo desde teclado

Tags: java

en un ejercicio viene esta sentencia:

```
if (carIn == 0) break;
```

carIn son caracteres que he leído de golpe mediante System.in.read(). Viendo la tabla ASCII veo que el 0 es el carácter NULL.

La pregunta es, qué debo de introducir por teclado para que esa condición sea cierta?

Gracias anticipadas.

Un cordial saludo

Comment: En Java los caracteres no usan el juego ASCII de caracteres amigo.

Comment: Bueno los 128 primeros caracteres son equivalentes, lo mismo pregunto para UNICODE sería equivalente

Answer (score 1):

Primero vamos a aclarar el propósito de `System.in`, y luego hablaremos del teclado.

Como está especificado, `System.in` es una clase tipo `InputStream` que como su nombre indica representa un flujo de bytes de entrada o entrantes.

En particular, el método `read()` de `System.in` lee un byte desde el dispositivo de entrada al que esté conectado el sistema.

En la consola, el dispositivo de entrada por defecto es el teclado.

Entonces, `read()` lee byte a byte lo que se introduzca por teclado, y luego debemos convertir dichos bytes a lo que vayamos a necesitar.

Un uso frecuente es convertir cada byte a un tipo `int`, y luego 'castear' dicho `int` a otro tipo, normalmente un `char`.

Por consola y usando el teclado, leemos los bytes de lo que se presione en el teclado, pero en el teclado no están representados todos los caracteres que existen.

Dependiendo del entorno (sistema operativo) existen atajos del teclado que nos permiten escribir caracteres que no están disponibles directamente en el teclado.

Si usamos MS Windows, normalmente podemos acceder a estos caracteres usando la combinación `alt + nnn`, donde `nnn` representa un entero que está asociado a un carácter en una tabla de códigos (ASCII o UNICODE).

Si usamos Linux, y específicamente `bash` en Linux, se accede a dichos caracteres usando `ctrl + shift + u + nnn`.

Lamentablemente no tengo un equipo con macOS para hacer pruebas, pero siendo que macOS usa también una implementación de terminal basada en `bash` imagino que el atajo de teclado es el mismo que en Linux.

En general, los primeros 128 caracteres de una tabla ASCII, son exactamente iguales en los S.O. más usados (Windows, Linux, macOS). Por lo tanto, el número 'nnn' que usemos en cualquiera de los tres ambientes nombrados ha de representar el mismo carácter en la tabla de códigos ASCII.

Ahora, en tu preguntas planteas ¿cómo escribir el carácter `null` en el teclado?.

Teniendo ahora el conocimiento de que los caracteres ASCII se pueden escribir usando atajos de teclado, de acuerdo al ambiente, se le puede ocurrir a alguien que si usa 'nnn = 0' debería funcionar.

El problema con esto es que aunque en la tabla ASCII, el valor cero (0) se asigna a `null`, el sistema operativo que maneja la interfaz de teclado a la cual se conecta  nuestro programa (al menos probado en Windows y en Linux), interpreta correctamente el código cero (0) como un carácter nulo, lo cual significa la ausencia de carácter, y por lo tanto no devuelve (pasa) nada a nuestro programa.

Así, es entonces imposible desde el teclado reproducir directamente el carácter `null` usando el método explicado anteriormente, debido a que son atajos inherentes al sistema operativo.

**SOLUCIÓN (Parcial)**

Sin embargo, existe una manera de escribir o enviar desde el teclado el carácter `null`. Y es usando un carácter de control.

Los carácter de control, son representaciones de caracteres de la tabla de códigos ASCII, y nos ayudan a enviar o escribir por teclado los caracteres no 'imprimibles' de dicha tabla.

Para enviar el carácter nulo se puede usar la notación de careta `^`, la cual consiste en sustraer 64 al código del carácter que se escriba después de la careta.

Por ejemplo, si deseamos representar el carácter `ACK` (6 de la tabla ASCII) usando notación de careta, buscaremos en la tabla ASCII el carácter correspondiente a 6 + 64, en este caso es 70 y corresponde al carácter `F`. Así podemos escribir: `^F`, lo cual es un carácter de control que representa el carácter `ACK` de la tabla ASCII.

El código ASCII 64, representa al carácter `@` en la tabla ASCII, por lo tanto, la notación de careta `^@` representará el carácter `null`.

El problema es que si escribimos directamente esto en la consola, el sistema enviará a nuestro programa los bytes correspondientes al carácter `^` y `@`, y el resultado no será el esperado.

Debemos usar un método de teclado, (funciona solo en sistemas tipo Unix, como Linux), que envía desde el teclado el carácter nulo. Dicho método es `ctrl + espacio`.

Lamentablemente Windows (probado en Windows 7) interpreta `ctrl + espacio` como un espacio normal, siendo su código ASCII = 32. (No he encontrado documentación sobre cómo pasar el carácter de control con notación de careta `^@` al terminal de Windows).

Puedes consultar la [Tabla ASCII - Códigos de carácter de control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart)

Al escribir esta combinación de teclas, el sistema efectivamente envía a la consola el byte correspondiente a dicho carácter.

Para terminar, siempre suelo subir código que pueda ser de utilidad para realizar pruebas o demostraciones. Dejo el siguiente código que puede ser usado para probar el envío de caracteres usando la secuencia de control arriba explicada.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class pruebaRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int codCaracter;
        System.out.println("Escriba un caracter:");
        try {
            codCaracter = System.in.read();
            System.out.println("Ha introducido: " + codCaracter);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error de lectura.");
        }
    }
}
```

El ¿porqué el código del ejercicio contempla el cero (0)?

Simplemente porque es una buena práctica de programación. El teclado es ciertamente el método de entrada estándar de `System.in`. Pero esto puede cambiarse con el método [`setIn()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)).

Imagina que cambiamos el método de entrada a digamos un puerto serie, el cual recibe bytes, y por el cual es posible recibir directamente un byte que representa el carácter `null`.

O como ya he planteado aqui, si usas un ambiente tipo Unix en el cual es posible enviar un carácter de control usando un método de teclado.

Es por eso que una buena implementación incluirá el carácter `null`, sea cual sea el propósito que luego pueda tener dicho carácter en el programa.

Espero que esto responda tu duda.